# Cannot Convert Lambda expression to type 'System.Type' because it is not a Delegate Type

Tags: c#, lambda, xamarin

I am working in Xamarin.Forms, to try and create a Pop Up window which contains a `ListView`.

I am trying to use this structure:

```
var PopUp = new StackLayout
{
 BackgroundColor = Color.Black, // for Android and WP
 Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
 Children =
 {
    PLZOrt_Label, // my Label on top
    SearchBarPLZOrt, // my SearchBar to the ListView
    LVPLZOrt, // The Listview (all Cities/Zip-Codes in the Datasource -> List)
 }
};
```

Taken from [this guide](http://www.matrixguide.ch/Datenablage/diverses/How_to_Implement_XLabs_PopUp_Control.pdf) page 13.

However, when I add a list view ( as detailed [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ListView/) ),

```
new Func<object> (delegate {
    ListView listView = new ListView {
    // Source of data items.
    ItemsSource = devices,

    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
    {
            // Create views with bindings for displaying each property.
            Label nameLabel = new Label();
            nameLabel.SetBinding(
            Label.TextProperty, "{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource strConverter}}"
            );

            Label IDLabel = new Label();
            IDLabel.SetBinding(
                Label.TextProperty, "{Binding Path=ID, Converter={StaticResource guidConverter}}"
                );

                return new ViewCell
                    {
                        View = new StackLayout
                    {
    })
});
```

The "ItemTemplate" line throws up a "Cannot Convert Lambda expression to type 'System.Type' because it is not a Delegate Type"

In some other issues like this, it seems the solutions was to add a `new action(() => {})` structure, but as this is a Xamarin approved method, I am not sure why I would need to implement this?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** With the addition of the top func line, I now get an error raised on that line, `Error CS1643: Not all code paths return a value in anonymous method of type 'System.Func<object>'`

Comment: What if you put your lambda inside `new Func<object>( ... )`?

Comment: @cubrr OK, I have wrappen all of my ListView code in a `new Func<object> (delegate { ...//all my code//...})` and have moved on from that error, but am now getting a `Not all code paths return a value in anonymous method of type 'System.Func<object>'` error?

Comment: Update your question with the code.

Comment: @cubrr Please see above

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant that if you could just add the actual code you have right now that is giving you the error.

Comment: I updated my answer with what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the constructors of `DataTemplate` [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.DataTemplate/), you need to either pass a `Func<object>` or a `Type`.

> [image]

**You need to return something** inside your [statement block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aba72.png) in order for it to be converted to a `Func<object>`. Since you have no return statement, the lambda isn't converted and the compiler thinks you're trying to use the `DataTemplate(Type)` constructor with wrong parameters. I don't know why the C# compiler chooses this constructor - I would guess that it's the first one it finds.

The example on the documentation page for the `ListView` page which you linked works because it returns a new `ViewCell`:

```
// ...
ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
{
    // Create views with bindings for displaying each property.
    Label nameLabel = new Label();
    nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");

    Label birthdayLabel = new Label();
    birthdayLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty,
        new Binding("Birthday", BindingMode.OneWay, 
                    null, null, "Born {0:d}"));

    BoxView boxView = new BoxView();
    boxView.SetBinding(BoxView.ColorProperty, "FavoriteColor");

    // Return an assembled ViewCell.  <<--------------------------------------
    return new ViewCell
    {
        View = new StackLayout
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(0, 5),
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            Children = 
            {
                boxView,
                new StackLayout
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Spacing = 0,
                    Children = 
                    {
                        nameLabel,
                        birthdayLabel
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
})
// ...
```

EDIT: This is what I meant by put the lambda inside a `new Func<object>(...):`

```
ListView listView = new ListView
{
    // Source of data items.
    ItemsSource = devices,

    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(new Func<object>(() =>
    {
        // Create views with bindings for displaying each property.
        Label nameLabel = new Label();
        nameLabel.SetBinding(
            Label.TextProperty, "{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource strConverter}}"
        );

        Label IDLabel = new Label();
        IDLabel.SetBinding(
            Label.TextProperty, "{Binding Path=ID, Converter={StaticResource guidConverter}}"
        );

        return new ViewCell
        {
            View = new StackLayout
        };
    }));
}
```

Comment: My Code with this error also returns a view cell , I'll edit my question to include